# How do I preview tag wiki exerpt? How do I put a link there?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, markdown-preview, tag-wiki-excerpt

I've edited [a tag](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/video/info) to include a link into exerpt. But it shows Markdown source of the link instead of actual link.

1. How do I preview the exerpt while editing it?
2. Where to find syntax and available Markdown features in exerpts?
3. How do I include the link properly?

Comment: Maybe split the question?...

Comment: Pick a tag that already has such content (such as the [hyperlinks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/5832) one you used) and see how that has been put together.

Comment: @JonW, The exerpt does not contain any links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag wiki excerpts can't contain Markdown or links - just plain text. Therefore there is nothing to "preview". What you are typing is what you will get.

Tag wiki bodies follow the same rules as questions and answers.

Comment: Will text like `http://something.com/` be still auto-converted to a link?

Comment: What alternative of a link should I use? Shall I write `There is also a dedicated video site video.stackexchange.com. Please see the tag wiki for further information` or shall I include the "unassisted" plaintext link?

Comment: @Vi. you can see that the link text hasn't been converted to a "real" hyperlink, so there is no point in including it in the excerpt.

Comment: @Vi.: no, URLs will not auto-link. URLs in tag excepts *do not work* and should never be used there.

Comment: This isn't *quite* true; there are some rules I don't fully understand that will trim off intro text from the beginning of an excerpt, and previewing *that* is non-trivial. But as far as actual formatting, yeah, plain text all the way.